# TypeOrm Save One-To-Many Object Relation

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have problem when trying to save object with one to many relation (mysql), it actually save only the top level entity. the generated query is

`` INSERT INTO `SeceneTemplates`(`Id`, `Name`, `Address`, `Rows`, `Cols`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["Pallati i Kongreseve","Sheshi Nene Tereza",5,5] ``

I don't know if there am doing smth wrong

it was supposed to generate three queries for each entity under a transaction
sorry since I am new on node and TypeORM, possibly I have missed smth
SeatsTemplate, ZoneTempalte and SeceneTemlate are entities and are loaded successfully.

**SeceneTemplates.ts**

```
import { ZoneTemplates } from "./ZoneTemplates";
import { Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Entity, OneToMany } from "typeorm";

@Entity("SeceneTemplates")
export class SeceneTemplates {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  Id: bigint;
  @Column()
  Name!: string;
  @Column()
  Address: string;
  @Column()
  Rows: number;
  @Column()
  Cols: number;

  @OneToMany(
    type => ZoneTemplates,
    zoneTemplate => zoneTemplate.sceneTemplate,
    { cascade: ["insert", "update", "remove"] }
  )
  zoneTemplates: ZoneTemplates[];

  public constructor(init?: Partial<SeceneTemplates>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

**ZoneTemaplate.ts**

```
import { SeceneTemplates } from "./SeceneTemplates";
import { SeatsTemplates } from "./SeatsTemplates";
import {
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany
} from "typeorm";

@Entity("ZoneTemplates")
export class ZoneTemplates {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  Id: bigint;
  @Column()
  Name!: string;
  @Column()
  Description: string;
  @Column()
  ColorCode: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => SeceneTemplates,
    sceneTemplate => sceneTemplate.zoneTemplates,
    { cascade: ["insert", "update", "remove"] }
  )
  sceneTemplate: SeceneTemplates;
  @OneToMany(
    type => SeatsTemplates,
    seatsTemplate => seatsTemplate.zoneTemplate,
    { cascade: ["insert", "update", "remove"] }
  )
  seatsTemplates: SeatsTemplates[];

  public constructor(init?: Partial<ZoneTemplates>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

**SeatsTemplates.ts**

```
import { SeceneTemplates } from "./SeceneTemplates";
import { ZoneTemplates } from "./ZoneTemplates";
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryColumn,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne
} from "typeorm";

@Entity("SeatsTemplates")
export class SeatsTemplates {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  Id: bigint;
  @Column()
  x: number;
  @Column()
  y: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => ZoneTemplates,
    zoneTemplate => zoneTemplate.seatsTemplates,
    { cascade: ["insert", "update", "remove"] }
  )
  zoneTemplate: ZoneTemplates;

  public constructor(init?: Partial<SeatsTemplates>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

**SceneService**

```
import { ISceneService } from "../interfaces/ISceneService";
import { CreateSceneRequestDTO } from "../../models/dto/Scenes/CreateSceneRequestDTO";
import { CreateSceneResponseDTO } from "../../models/dto/Scenes/CreateSceneResponseDTO";
import { SeceneTemplates } from "../../models/data/SeceneTemplates";
import { ZoneTemplates } from "../../models/data/ZoneTemplates";
import { SeatsTemplates } from "../../models/data/SeatsTemplates";
import { createConnection, getConnectionManager } from "typeorm";

export class SceneService implements ISceneService {
  createScene(request: CreateSceneRequestDTO): Promise<CreateSceneResponseDTO> {
    return new Promise<CreateSceneResponseDTO>(async (resolve, rejects) => {
      let createSceneResponse: CreateSceneResponseDTO = new CreateSceneResponseDTO(
        {
          code: "999",
          message: "Internal Server Error",
          success: false
        }
      );

      const connection = getConnectionManager().get("default");

      const eventRepository = connection.getRepository(SeceneTemplates);

      let newSceneTemplate = new SeceneTemplates({
        Name: request.sceneName,
        Rows: request.rows,
        Cols: request.columns,
        Address: request.address
      });

      let newZoneTemplates = request.areas.map(val => {
        return new ZoneTemplates({
          ColorCode: val.color,
          Name: val.name,
          Description: val.description,
          sceneTemplate: newSceneTemplate
        });
      });

      newZoneTemplates.forEach((v, k) => {
        newZoneTemplates[k].seatsTemplates = request.seats
          .filter(e => e.color === v.ColorCode)
          .map(seatVal => {
            return new SeatsTemplates({
              x: seatVal.x,
              y: seatVal.y,
              zoneTemplate: v
            });
          });
      });

      newSceneTemplate.zoneTemplates = newZoneTemplates;

      eventRepository
        .save(newSceneTemplate)
        .then((currentScene: SeceneTemplates) => {
          createSceneResponse.message = "Success";
          createSceneResponse.code = "200";
          createSceneResponse.success = true;
          createSceneResponse.SceneId = currentScene.Id;

          resolve(createSceneResponse);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          createSceneResponse.message = "Failed to save the scene";
          createSceneResponse.code = "500";
          createSceneResponse.success = false;

          rejects(createSceneResponse);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used cascade option like { cascadeInsert: true }